# dynamic url change issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I want to change my URL  from `https://website.com/free?s=new-check` to  `https://website.com/free/new-check/`

My Current htaccess code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /free\?s=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ /free?s=$1 [NC,L]
```

It works and directed to `https://website.com/new-check` but what I want is `https://website.com/free/new-check/`
previously I removed the .php extension from the URL.

I tried a lot of solutions but nothing works. please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess Rules. Make sure to keep these Rules at top of your htaccess file if you have other Rules also in your file.

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On
##https apply rules here.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

##External redirect Rule here.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(free)\?s=([^\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [L,R=301]

##Internal rewrite rule here.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]*)/(.*)/?$ free.php?s=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. It reflects in url bar but that "free" name takes as a directory. so I got an Internal Server Error in [link](https://website.com/free/new-check). i manually tried [link] (https://website.com/free.php/new-check)it  works. but i don't want .php within URL @RavinderSignh13

Comment: @MildMilly, ok, could you please try my updated code once? Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. Let me know how it goes then.

Comment: Thank You again for your great effort. No luck for me this time I got 
Page Not Found - 404 Error. @RavinderSignh13

Comment: @MildMilly, ok so your pages https://website.com/free?s=new-check ate Getting served by index.php file? Please confirm once

Comment: i Have 2 pages. i want the result in my redirection. 1)index.php 2)free.php 
My index.php file contain <a href="free?s=new-check">Go</a> link thats redirected to free.php @RavinderSingh13

Comment: @MildMilly, ok so which redirection to go to index.php and which one should go to free.php? Could you please elaborate more on this one?

Comment: with your update, I got a result index.php result in https://website.com/free/new-check URL @RavinderSingh13

Comment: @MildMilly, yeah, that's why I was asking which link/url should be served by index.php and which url from free.php? could you please elaborate on this one.

Comment: You Made My Day !  Its Work!

Just i changed the file name  RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]*)/(.*)/?$ free.php?s=$1 [NC,QSA,L] .

The Index.php file just has one button when I check the go button it takes me to free.php with values  Like www.website.com/free/s=new-check. 

Thank you so much! really you made my day! @RavinderSingh13

Comment: @MildMilly, Your welcome. Very happy that I could help you, cheers and happy learning, keep posting Good Q & A on this great forum.

Comment: No Words to Say! Thank You Again! Have a Great Day!  @RavinderSingh13

Comment: I need one more favor.  Now I have one more file called "new.php" it redirected the same as the previous link. website.com/new/John-smith (org URL: website.com/new?s=John-smith )but I have an issue with the result. website.com/new/John-smith loads "free.php" file with "s=John-smith" values.

Example: consider free.php contains `Hi, $_GET['s']`. new.php contains  `Hello world, $_GET['s']` . when i run website.com/new/John-smith it gives me "Hi John-smith" .i edited the htaccess file same as "free" but no luck. @RavinderSingh13